# Ubuntu network interface restart issue

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have an ubuntu 12.04-lts server running with two network cards, eth0 and eth1. When I try to restart the network, I get "Failed to up start eth0". When I do ifconfig, both network cards show different static IP. Funny thing is that I'm able to ssh into the server using eth0 IP address.

My question is why am I getting "Failed to up start eth0"  message when I restart the network.

Thanks in adavnce

**update**

if use lshw -C class command, I get

```
-network:0             
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
....
-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.1
       logical name: eth1
....
```

Comment: What does `/var/log/syslog` say?

Comment: Do you use network-manager ? If it is the case, you must restart the interface from it. Could you give us the command you use to restart your interface ?

Comment: @Dom /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Do you use network-manager ? You can not use  /etc/init.d/networking restart if it is the case, as network-manager don't use /etc/network/interfaces...

Comment: @EEAA tailed syslog file while executing /etc/init.d/networking restart, i get no logs!!! i don't get this.

Comment: Thanks @Dom however far as i can see network-manager is not installed in the server. it may have been installed and someone removed it later. if it was installed where is the connection file (like /etc/network/interfaces)

Comment: I don't know where the conf are and how restart the interfaces. There is a graphical interface to do that.

Comment: can you provide the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and the files /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections (if that dir exists)

Comment: sorry for the late response however this issue is now resolved. i did not do anything fancy other then reboot the server and it started working.